# Printing text on different size of paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

We are developing a shopping cart for greeting cards where user can select card and specify customized messages to be printed on that car. The cards vary in size and the location of the customized text to be printed also varies. We need to show the image of card on the web page and user should be able to write text on the card's image and drag the text to specific location.

While stumbling I found there is a Firefox plugin ([js-print-setup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/)) for modifying printing options from the browser itself. But I don't know how to place text at specific location on the image.

I am not well verse with printing and UI/UX technologies. Could anyone please give me pointer how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can only trigger printing from your page, you cannot force certain printing settings (like page size etc.).

All you can do is create a printable version of your "page" by [creating a print stylesheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/). To achieve that, you have to use one of the CSS media types called `print`.

```
@media print {
    ....
}
```

Here you can define a separate look for your page that is used when you print your page. You can do something clever and prepare different styles for different situations.

However like I said, there is no cross-browser Javascript solution that allows you to change or affect the printer's settings.